# How to unremove files before first commit on git?

Tags: git

I accidentally did a

```
git rm filename.txt -f
```

I removed all my files thinking it would only remove them from the commit, now need to recover them. Is there a way or are they lost for good?

Comment: Did you `git add filename.txt` before? If so, you may be able to recover the file from Git's object store.

Comment: Try `git reset --hard` instead.

Comment: Assuming you never made any commits, you can only get the data back *from Git* if you ran `git add` on the various files. You will lose the file's *names*. If you did not even run `git add`, try some non-Git solution, such as editor backups, macOS Time Machine, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title of your question seems to indicate no commit was done on your repo.

In that case :

- unfortunately, if some changes on `filename.txt` weren't *staged* (e.g: weren't present in the last `git add filename.txt` that your ran), `git` doesn't have a copy of that file, you would have to look at other tools to get that file back from disk (several IDEs keep a local history of your files, or you can run disk recovery tools)
- the version that was *staged* (when you last ran `git add filename.txt`), however, is still present somewhere in `git`'s database

See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53068863/86072) for one possible way to get back some data from git's storage :

```
#!/bin/sh

git fsck --no-reflogs --unreachable |\
    grep blob |\
    cut -d' ' -f3 |\
    sed -e 's|^\(..\)\(.*\)|.git/objects/\1/\2|' |\
    xargs ls -l -t 2> /dev/null
```

This should give you a list of hashes, and one of these hashes should be the content of your file. The list will be sorted in "most recent first" oerder, so with some luck your last file will be listed among the first ones.

You can run `git show {hash}` to view the content of the file behind a hash, and `git show {hash} > back-from-the-dead.txt` to restore it to a file on disk.

Comment: Thanks, this gave me all the files in one txt but it's something! not lost after all!

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
git reset head ~
```

If you staged your commit you can recover it, otherwise it's probably dead forever.

Comment: I get the following error fatal: ambiguous argument 'head': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Comment: Try `git reset --hard` instead. But if you have never committed your files, that won’t work and the files can never be recovered.

Comment: Seems since I didn't commit I can't recover them, thanks anyway.

Comment: Always spell `HEAD` in all uppercase (or, if you don't want to bother, use `@` for short). The lowercase version sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't. In this particular case—when there are no commits yet—neither one works though....