# Restore files after git merge --abort

Tags: git, github, git-merge

```
git merge --abort
```

then it went back to latest commit head and deleted all my files.

My project was on merging stage and I did

```
git add 
git commit -m "message"
```

then it didnt allow me to commit saying "cannot do a partial commit during merge"
then I aborted merge by

```
git merge --abort
```

Then it deleted all my files and went back to last commit stage. This cause me lose all my files and codes i did in between.

> How to recover all my files that i had before i ran **git merge --abort**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restore git files deleted after git merge --abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468125/restore-git-files-deleted-after-git-merge-abort)

Comment: didnt help. asked the question after hearing out many options.

Comment: Are you including that period in the command?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No. that is typo

Comment: Make sure to resolve _all conflicts_ by making the changes and _adding all_ of those files before committing. I think this is why you're getting the partial commit error. You can't recover the files if your IDE doesn't have them in it's history. This is similar to resetting (hard) before you've added or committed changes.