# Undo 'git reset --hard' before first commit

Tags: git

Basically I had a codebase on my local machine, I ran:

```
git init

git add .
```

At this point, I realized I wanted to add a **.gitignore** file.

So I thought I needed to unstage commits, and in an amateur move, executed the following command

```
git reset --hard
```

Now my entire code base is gone...

Is it possible to undo this!?

Comment: Not without a backup or filesystem support for retrieving deleted files. You did the equivalent of `rm *`.

Comment: Ouch! It hurts to read this question. It doesn't look like there is a commit to go back to.

Comment: The content of your files is not entirely lost, but it will be a bit of a mess to reconstruct your directory of code files. Did you have many distinct files in your inital git add ?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468125/restore-git-files-deleted-after-git-merge-abort/39469723#39469723)

Comment: Well yeah, it was a backend project in node.  So from it's root folder i had a few directories with various files,    models  routes   src/index...   etc

Comment: See also [git-recover](https://github.com/ethomson/git-recover/blob/main/git-recover).

Comment: Similar question with interesting answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094968/in-git-how-can-i-recover-a-staged-file-that-was-reverted-prior-to-committing/58853981#58853981

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git add .` has added the *content* of your files into git ; unfortunately, it hasn't created a 'directory' structure which lists your files with their *names*.

What you can do :

run

```
git fsck --full --unreachable --no-reflog | grep blob > blobs.txt

# the content of blobs.txt will look like :
unreachable blob 08bf360988858a012dab3af4e0b0ea5f370a2ae8
unreachable blob 21bf7ea93f9f9cc2b3ecbed0e5ed4fa45c75eb89
unreachable blob 08c12ef37075732cf4645269ab5687ba6ba68943
...
```

For each of these blobs, you can dump the content to disk :

```
cat blobs.txt | awk '{ print $3 }' | while read blobid; do
    git show $blobid > $blobid.txt
done
```

You will now have a list of files :

```
08bf360988858a012dab3af4e0b0ea5f370a2ae8.txt
21bf7ea93f9f9cc2b3ecbed0e5ed4fa45c75eb89.txt
08c12ef37075732cf4645269ab5687ba6ba68943.txt
...
```

The good news is : all the files that were present in the initial `git add .` should be represented in there.

The bad news is :

- this list will also contain the files you wanted to ignore initially (I assume you added your `node_modules/` folder, so you would have the code for all the js libs you added ...) ,
- you will have to figure out what files went where, and rename them to `src/my_controller.js`, `src/model/my_model.js` ...

---

One first filter you could apply, to try to take the `node_modules/` files away is :

- in the list of blobs above, try to find your package.json file (`grep -e some_package_I_remember`),
- rename it to `package.json` (you may also find the lockfile), and run `npm install` or `yarn install`
- this should create a `node_modules/` folder, which looks a lot like the previous one you had
- add that `node_modules/` folder, and create a commit,
- now, the blobs in node_modules are no longer unreachable ; re-run the `git fsck ... > blobs.txt` above, you should have a list of what *wasn't* under `node_modules` ...

Comment: Thank you for the help!