# Revert (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

Tags: git

I accidentally ran this command and lost my code. Is it revertable?

`git checkout -- folder/*`

Comment: Unfortunately, all the changes that weren't committed or staged are not stored in git. Hopefully your IDE keeps a track of the successive states of your files when you hit `Ctrl+S`, or you can turn to a file recovery tool for your OS.

Comment: If your code was staged (as in `git add folder/myfile` or `git add folder`) at some point, and your actual sequence of commands was `git reset HEAD; git checkout -- folder/*`, you may look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39469723/86072)

Answer (score 2):

Since it is *not* revertible, check your IDE in which you developed that code.

If you have a recent enough VSCode, you should be able to:

- recreate the file (empty)
- check the [timeline view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71501328/6309) which provides a local history of said file, allowing you to restore a past content (even when not saved in a Git commit)

That supposes however that you remember how those files were named.

The other option is to check if you had [activated Time Machine on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250).

In the future, use [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) instead of `git checkout`: it deals only with branches, and will not override files.