# Undo git reset -- file, git checkout -- file

Tags: git

I was using a Git tool that ran `git reset -- myfile.dart` and `git checkout -- myfile.dart` which discarded changes against my wishes.

Is there any way to restore these discarded changes?

I can't find anything in `git reflog` to help me restore.

Comment: If the changes weren't committed, no.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a direct way, the good news though is that since your file was `git add`ed its *content* is still somewhere in git internal storage.

---

Copying the content of my answer to this other question :
[Restore git files deleted after git merge --abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468125/restore-git-files-deleted-after-git-merge-abort/39469723#39469723)

Run :

```
git fsck --full --unreachable --no-reflog | grep blob
```

(note: "blob" is the internal word for "file" within git storage).

This should give you a list of internal git hashes :

```
unreachable blob 08bf360988858a012dab3af4e0b0ea5f370a2ae8
unreachable blob 21bf7ea93f9f9cc2b3ecbed0e5ed4fa45c75eb89
unreachable blob 08c12ef37075732cf4645269ab5687ba6ba68943
...
```

note that `git add myfile.dart` stores the file's *content*, not the file's *name* ...

If you remember a specific string in your file, you can try to narrow your research by using `git grep <string> <hash>` :

```
$ git fsck --full --unreachable --no-reflog | grep blob | awk '{ print $3 }' > list.txt
$ cat list.txt | while read blob; do
  if git grep -q "string" $blob; then
    echo $blob
  fi
done
```

You can then view the whole content of a blob using :

```
git show $blob
```

and hopefully find back the file you were looking for :

```
git show $blob > myfile.dart
```