# Show all git commits over all branches

Tags: git, github

Something mysterious happened and the local git branch I was working on disappeared.  I have no idea where it went.

Is there any way to list all commits that have ever been made across all branches, even ones that aren't around any more?

Comment: 'git reflog' should give the HEAD history, then you can checkout to specific commit that might be listed there.

Comment: @zatta git reflog doesn't show any commits since I branched

Comment: Afaik, reflog is global and at least should show you commits you made recently. Are you sure you are in the correct project directory locally? More verbose command would be `git reflog --all`

Answer (score 0):

> [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) doesn't show any commits since I branched

That means you might not have committed sonce you have branched.
Maybe your files were added to the index but were since removed from disk?
As [seen in this guide](http://www.programblings.com/2008/06/07/the-illustrated-guide-to-recovering-lost-commits-with-git/) (or in "[Recover from git reset --hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5788069/6309)"), check the result of:

```
git fsck −−lost-found
```

([more complete command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10783950/6309): `git fsck --full --unreachable --no-reflog`)