# How to get file back when you delete in case dont commit

Tags: git

How can take file back after delete before commit
Because i have a mistake that is delete whole current file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I do not understand what you are trying to ask. Please take some time to [edit] your question so it is more clear. Be sure to use complete sentences. Often several short sentences are easier to understand than one long sentence.

Comment: sorry guys, because now i'm so crazzy. Now my effort has gone i dont know what to do

Comment: Was this file ever committed previously? Did you delete a file which is already tracked by version control with git?

Comment: "*before commit*"? What commit?

Comment: actually not a file
that's a lots of files

Comment: that's mean you still not commit and then you delete some file
but that's file its not on git server

Comment: What do you mean by "git server"?

Comment: sorry, my english is not good 
thats not in log

Answer (score 1):

> after I code but I commit in branch b, but I want to push in branch a

If you did commit, check `git reflog`: you will find your past commits there.

If you added the file to the index, but deleted it *before* a commit, you might be able to find it back [using `git fsck --lost-found`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14988152/6309).

But if it was deleted before ever being recorded by Git... check out editor/IDE. Some have a local history which could have recorded a version of that file.

Comment: that's up to your editor to support. i find in history file. but it's just very less. almost just a little bit tiny.
Hope that helpful!!