# Recover lost files after added and doing git reset --hard

Tags: git, reset

How to recover files after **adding** and doing **git reset --hard**?

Here are some points that must consider before answer:

- Raw .git directory
- No initial commit
- .git directory has size of **67.3 MBs**

Sequence of git commands that cause damage

1. git add .
2. git reset --hard

Kindly help me out to recover my project source code files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recovering added file after doing git reset --hard HEAD^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108853/recovering-added-file-after-doing-git-reset-hard-head)

Comment: I tried that solution but it didn't work for me.

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782978/recover-files-that-were-added-to-the-index-but-then-removed-by-a-git-reset/10783950#comment42371725_14988152? `for b in $(git fsck --lost-found | grep blob | awk '{print $3}'); do git cat-file -p $b > ../$b ; done`

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: I'm using windows 8.1 x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you  have your **.git** folder 
go to  your project dir in which **.git** folder lies.
use this

> git fsck --lost-found

it  will  generate  a  folder in **.git** directory **lost-found**
you can  see  a  blob  there,it hasn't  named files but  you  can see  your code  in  these files.