# How to recover after i execute :git reset --hard HEAD

Tags: ios, git

I made a terrible mistake and execute "git reset --hard HEAD", all day's the local modification lost, how can i recover it?

Thanks millions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recovering added file after doing git reset --hard HEAD^](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1108853/456814).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you didn't already commit your local changes (or at least stage them via `git add`, they're gone. `git reset --hard` is a destructive operation for uncommitted changes.

If you did happen to stage them, but didn't commit them, try `git fsck --lost-found` and then search through the contents of `.git/lost-found` - it will contain all of the objects that aren't referenced by a known commit, and may include versions of files that were staged.

Comment: `git fsck --lost-found` save my life, thank you very much.

Comment: Use git reflog as stated in the next answer.

Answer (score 30):

You can use `git reflog`. It will show `HEAD` history. You can pick the hash that represents the HEAD status before the `git reset --hard` and use this hash in another `git reset --hard` .

Comment: This saved me. This MUST be the acepted answer!!

Comment: Thank you so much for this! A real life saver in my situation!

Answer (score 18):

First run:

```
git reflog
```

It will show history of your HEAD pointer.
Then select sha-code of a necessary state from first column. I think it will be near HEAD@{1} if you made just git reset --hard once.
And then

```
git merge SHA_CODE
```

Bingo!

More examples you can find here:
http://www.programblings.com/2008/06/07/the-illustrated-guide-to-recovering-lost-commits-with-git/

Comment: You made my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can recover anything you `git add`ed, with `git fsck --lost-found` and poke around in `.git/lost-found`.  `find .git/objects -type f | xargs ls -lt | sed 60q` will give you the last 60 things to get added to the repo, that'll help.

Anything you didn't `git add` is gone as surely as if you'd deleted it yourself.

Comment: I didn't do commit or do add operation before that

Answer (score 1):

If your IDE has something like a "Local history" (Eclipse has this, IDEA also AFAIK), then maybe you can recover your changes this way.

Answer (score 0):

I recovered the files not "git add"-ed with my Intelliji "local history".