# Recover commits after multiple hard resets?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a branch that has a lot of changes from many commits back from master. It merged master a couple weeks ago and it auto merged and seemed fine.

I merged master into it today and since there was a big update that was pulled into master, I had a lot of conflicts. I went through and (thought) I successfully fixed conflicts, there was lots of errors and seemed like the auto merge had not gone as planned. I reset back to a hash I thought was before this merge and then force pushed that to origin, hoping I was able to just try again and do it more methodically.

However, now looking through my local and remote branch, I can't find any of the commits that were in this branch to begin with. I'm using Bitbucket and I'm not as well versed on searching for commits as I am with Github, but I've also been using `gitk` and `git log --oneline --graph --decorate` with no success of finding anything.

I restored to looking at a copy of the repo on my laptop that is outdated but has the commits on the branch in question. I was able to search for it via hash on Bitbucket and found the commit is there, but doesn't seem to be in the repo.

If it's unsalvageable (which I hope and doubt), my only option would be to go from the outdated version on my laptop and figure out what is missing and go from there.

I'm very confused at to what I have achieved and don't want to make the situation worst, happy to provide any more info.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is much simpler than I expected.

1. `git reflog | grep '{name of branch}'`
2. Find commit that caused problems and copy the hash of the `HEAD` before that commit. (e.g. mine was `checkout: moving from master to {name of branch}`)
3. `git reset {commit hash} --hard`

Then since I wanted to repair my remote branch as well, I did `git push -f`.

Comment: Mere repetition of https://stackoverflow.com/a/14252416/341994

Comment: @matt Different solution.