# get uncommited changes back in a branch

Tags: git

I changed files on a `branch`, let's call it `foo`, and then added them to track:

```
git add folder/
```

However, I forgot to `commit` and forced checkout to another branch.

Is there any way to get those `uncommited` changes on `foo` branch back?

Comment: Looks like a near duplicate of eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108853/recovering-added-file-after-doing-git-reset-hard-head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
By forcing checkout, you destroyed your changes.

In general, `--force` or `--hard` in git means that you're destroying something.

Instead, you should have `git stash`ed first.