# Git how can I restore local version previously overwriting by remote repository

Tags: git

I make sth really stiupid I enter this command (In that time I dont know exactly what it does):

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

and as follows later it probably overwrites my local version with this from remote repository, which is totally NOT what i want to do.

Could you plz tell me how can I restore my local version ? I assume it may be impossible, but I do hope it can be done in some way. I work on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Had you ever staged those changes with `git add` or ever committed them with `git commit`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undoing a git reset --hard HEAD~1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/undoing-a-git-reset-hard-head1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recover the state before by referring the "previous state of HEAD" with the following command:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

This will work if committed the changes you were making.

If you haven't committed, but only staged, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108853/recovering-added-file-after-doing-git-reset-hard-head/1109433#1109433).

If you haven't committed or staged, you'll have lost everything, except if your IDE/text editor has some recovery features, or backups.

Comment: That would require the changes to actually have been committed in order to work, just having been staged would not be enough.