# "git reset --hard HEAD" after "git commit --amend"

Tags: git

I performed `git commit --amend`.

I made some changes, but wanted to discard them, so I then performed `git reset --hard HEAD`, thinking it would go back to the point I amended. It seems to have gone back to the point of the original commit.

There are numerous answers to undoing a `git reset --hard HEAD` on here, but none specifically that deal with a undoing a `reset` in this situation (with an `amend` involved), and I just wanted to make sure I should follow the same pattern before proceeding.

This seems to be the most popular answer:
[How can I undo git reset --hard HEAD~1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/undoing-a-git-reset-hard-head1)

EDIT

You know what, I'm realizing I've done a couple of `--amend`s today without first doing `git add .`. What a crappy day. Is there any way to get back the work if I didn't `git add .`?

Comment: Don't think there's any way besides possible file system features (like Windows' shadow copies), if the changes/files have never been in any commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `git commit --amend` involved any content modification (git add), then the `git reset --hard` would have worked as expected.

But `git commit --amend` without any modification would simply modify the commit date (hence changing/SHA1 the commit SHA1)

If those changes were added, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21227533/6309) shows that [`git fsck`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck) should be able to show you those changes.

A more complete command (in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1109433/6309)) would be:

```
git fsck --cache --no-reflogs --lost-found --unreachable  HEAD
```

More at "[Recovering added file after doing `git reset --hard HEAD^`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15472831/6309)".