# Recover deleted files from using git rm -r

Tags: git, git-rm

Unknowingly, without finding out what the command does, i used the git rm -r command on a folder of a proyect thinking it would delete all files only inside that folder. To my surprise, all my files where deleted.

I found a way to recover my files from my last commit (about 3 days ago) using the following commands:

```
git reset
git checkout -- $(git ls-files -d)
```

Now my question is, all the work i have done during that last 3 days, is there ny way i can recover this? Even if its just the files so i can copy and paste. All the files deleted where atleast added to the repository, im trying to find a way to either recover my project the way it was before i did git rm -r or if i can recoverd the files individual so i can copy and past. Thank you for any help

Comment: You've learned a very valuable lesson today.  Commit often. And I'm guessing you'll never forget what that command does again.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the files are added to the repo (not yet committed), there is a chance to recover them.

See "[Recovering added file after doing git reset --hard HEAD^](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1109433/6309)"

```
git fsck --cache --no-reflogs --lost-found --dangling HEAD
cd .git/lost-found/other
```

But the surest way remains to commit often indeed.