# Restore not committed files in GIT

Tags: git, commit, restore, git-commit

I have pushed one of my branch before committing the changes and then checked out to another branch. then I have done git reset to make this branch similar to origin. Also the remote branch has been deleted. Now when I switch back to the first branch, I am not seeing the files which was there. These files has been added , but not committed. How can I restore the files ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1108853/4289417. "git fsck --cache --no-reflogs --lost-found --unreachable HEAD" should help.

Comment: This has given me an unreachable blob. Now what I can do with that  ?

Comment: Err no you can't check it out actually. See the link for details, but you can run, for example "git show -p --format=raw $blob" on it, etc. Also see .git/lost-found.

Comment: Yes done it. You saved my day

Comment: You should add that as a answer @PavelChernikov. That's some serious git magic! :)

Answer (score -1):

Run the following to show unreachable git objects:

```
git fsck --cache --no-reflogs --lost-found --unreachable HEAD
```

To place them in .git/lost-found, skip the --unreachable flag.