# how to find uncommitted code after pulled git

Tags: git, android-studio, bitbucket

I wrote some code and didn't committed it. after that today I pulled git and lost my uncommitted code.

How can I find it?
tools: android studio, bitbucked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have added those files to the git repo index, [you can still recover their content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15472831/6309).

If not, try and see if the [IntelliJ local history](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/using-local-history.html) still has trace of those files.
Note: there are [limitations to the local history feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/local-history.html).

Comment: thank you, I have checked Intellij local history, which is much easier than git local history