# undo git reset --hard, how to do it?

Tags: git, git-reflog

My uncommitted files deleted by `git reset --hard` command. How can I recover? I tried `git reflog` etc but it stays at 0%.

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.ories:   0% (1/256)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the output of your `git reflog` and/or which command you did then?

Comment: @GaëlJ https://prnt.sc/134ru9u

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice you said uncommited files, these one are lost if you mean uncommited in the sense of never tracked by Git

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recovering added/staged file after doing git reset --hard HEAD^?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108853/recovering-added-staged-file-after-doing-git-reset-hard-head)

Answer (score 2):

For staged file, you can check the [output in git fsck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1109433/6309), but for private files, as in not even staged (`git add`), then those files are gone.
[`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) would only help to restore past *commits*.

Double-check with:

- your OS for any backup in place (like [Time Machine on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/back-up-files-mh35860/mac))
- your IDE for any local history (like [Jetbrain IntelliJ IDEA local history](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html)), which could help restore those deleted files.

Answer (score 1):

If you have **staged** your file, you can try `git fsck --lost-found` then take a look into `.git/lost-found/other` and using `git show <SHA>` check what you can recover

So I've recreated your scenario: (created `new_file` then stage it, and `git reset --hard` afterwards)

[image]

Checked the content of `.git/lost-found/other`
[image]

Then recover the content `git show <SHA>`:
[image]

Fortunately in my case I had a small number of commits so it was easy to find it.