# Retrieve status from yesterday without having done a push

Tags: git

I have a big problem. I used the command 'git reset --hard origin/master' to delete my entire directory WITHOUT pushing it first! Then I closed VS, PC off, on again. How can I restore the state I had last night? If I use 'git reflog, it only shows me the statuses of a few minutes today
'

Comment: Are you sure you are running reflog from the same directory? And that whenever you ran rest was not exactly those few minutes ago?

Comment: Remote repositories are not a substitute for regular backups of your local disk.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [undo git reset --hard, how to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67609651/undo-git-reset-hard-how-to-do-it)

Comment: @radschapur of course I'm sure!