# Is There A Way To Retrieve My Progress (Git)

Tags: git, version-control

I had added a bunch of files and directories to the staging area with git add --all. After that I received this message "CRLF will be replaced by LF". So I searched up how to solve this problem and came across a medium article which said to type in the following commands.

1. $ git config --global core.autocrlf input
2. $ git rm --cached -r . && git reset --hard

After running that I lost all my changes. Is there a way to get back all the changes I made so that I was were I was before running the commands. Thanks.

All the commands I ran:

1. git add --all
2. git config --global core.autocrlf input
3. git rm --cached -r . && git reset --hard

Comment: I don't even see a problem!

Comment: All my progress was lost. I want to get it back.

Comment: Your progress is lost. `git rm` removed your staged changes and `git reset` removed any changes that weren't staged.

Comment: Yeah, but the original "problem", the warning about line ending conversion, wasn't a problem to begin with.

Comment: It may be restorable, check out: [Recovering added/staged file after doing git reset --hard HEAD^?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1109433)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+recover+uncommitted+hard+reset