# Recovering a git reset --soft

Tags: git, reset

I modified some files in my branch and did a

```
git add --all
```

But this added some files that I didn't intend to add for the commit.

So I did a

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2 (instead of doing git reset HEAD)
```

But the previous commit was made by someone else and it caused a lot of files to be in modified/added/deleted status. Is there a way to get back to a stage where the only changes I see are the files added/modified by me? Since I didnt make an actual commit, is there a way to move my head back to master without blowing away my changes? git pull is causing merge conflicts as I didn't actually commit my changes.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably did a `git reset --soft`, not a `git soft --reset` :-)

Comment: Related to [Undoing git reset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510276/undoing-git-reset).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do `git reset master`. This will only update the index and what `HEAD` points to. It will not modify your work tree files.

Comment: Doesn't look like it will work because I did a git reset --hard HEAD@{1} to undo my soft reset (from reflog). It blew away my changes. So is there a way to get the changes back after hard reset if you never commited (but added and soft reset'ed) those changed files? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, no. If you've never committed a change and that change is removed from the work tree, there is no way to get it back.

Answer (score 15):

For future reference, you can review the commits that your behavior causes or leaves behind by calling `git reflog` , which will include commits that are no longer in your working tree.

Comment: Does that mean I can move back to a previous stage in my branch that is recorded in reflog? If yes, how?

Comment: Looks like I can do this by a git reset --hard <reflog_id>. But my problem is there is no reflog for the changes I added as I never commited them. :(

Comment: Oy.  `git reset --hard` is a synonym for "delete some stuff if necessary", so you have to use it as a last last resort, when you're sure you've nothing that needs backing up.  Sorry, I should have specified that I was giving a +1 vote to dan's command, the reflog is useful for added info, and will show -everything- that git does record.  I believe that leaves adding stuff to the index out of the running.

Comment: Looks like git reflog doesn't record info about changes added but not committed. Thank you Dan and Tchalvak for the answers.

Answer (score -1):

A visual solution: open git gui:

```
git gui
```

At bottom at the *Commit Message* box choose the radio button labeled *Amend Last Commit*. You'll see at the left the *Staged Changes* area. It contains the files you have added in the last commit. Click on the icons of the files you don't want in your commit to remove them from the index. Afterwards just commit again by pressing the *Commit* button.

Comment: Keep in mind that git gui is not installed by default when you install git. I don't actually know what that command is so you may want to clarify what it is and how to get it so people don't downvote your answer.