# Can "undo" my last "undo" in Git?

Tags: git

I did:

```
git reset --soft ^HEAD
```

when I guess I really meant:

```
git reset --soft HEAD
```

Now all of my day's work is "gone". Is it possible to move back up the ladder to capture what I did today

The reason I did the reset is because I initially did:

```
git commit -a -m "xyz"
```

instead of:

```
git commit -m "xyz"
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510276/undoing-git-reset)  or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/undoing-a-git-reset-hard-head1)?

Comment: Yes. But unfortunately, when I take that action it shows my changes in REVERSE! So my code is *somewhere* in git, just not where I need it. I guess there's no way to put the genie back in the bottle with git, at least not without being a computer scientist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git reflog` is the safety net surrounding all the wonderful git craziness. You can use it to locate the hash of your commit previous to your "undo", check that out to a branch (to be safe) and then restore your working tree from there.

More details [here](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/05/git-tip-of-week-reflogs.html)

Comment: It appears I was downvoted without a comment. I'd appreciate the feedback if there is a better way to do things : )

Answer (score 0):

Use `git-reflog`:

```
git reflog
# find SHA of commit which you "lost"
git reset --hard SHA
```

Finding the exact commit may be tricky, but you can inspect each commit in the reflog with `git show`.

Comment: I initially did a "git reset --soft". I have managed to sort of get back to where I can "see" my changes, but they are all backwards. In other words, they aren't in the files. "git status" shows my next commit as basically undoing everything I had before.

Comment: Provided that you added your changes to git at some point, you will be able to see them in the reflog (assuming gc hasn't run).  Every time you do a commit or add, the reflog moves forward...so you should always be able to get back to where you once were.