# How to revert an unnecessary "git reset HEAD~1"

Tags: git

After running `git reset HEAD~1`, I noticed that actually there was nothing else to do and the commit was fine. Is there a way to revert this command?

Comment: Where you on a branch when you ran that, or a detached head?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undoing git reset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510276/undoing-git-reset)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can use:

```
git reset HEAD@{1}
```

This uses the last entry in the reflog. See `git reflog` if you did other things in between.

Comment: this worked perfectly. If I used 2 instead of 1, it would go back 2 steps, right?

Comment: Exactly. Have a look at `git reflog` to see which number corresponds to which commit. Have a look at `man gitrevisions` for those kinds of special syntax.

Comment: always forget about reflog ><

Answer (score 12):

You could see the commit id of that commit with `git reflog`.

Answer (score 3):

Even easier (if you haven't done any other operations):

```
git reset ORIG_HEAD
```

`ORIG_HEAD` is the previous state of `HEAD`.

More details about `HEAD` vs. `ORIG_HEAD` are in the [answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git).