# Undo git reset --soft ~HEAD

Tags: git

I was going to add some changes using git.
Instead of committing my changes, I managed to write git reset --soft ~HEAD.
How do I undo this command and get my changes back?

Comment: Have your working files been changed?

Comment: After git reset --soft ~head, my changes dissapeared and the files from another commit appeared in my git status

Comment: I managed to fix this myself. Found this command and it worked: git reset HEAD@{1}. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2531803/470749 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/7844566/470749 helped me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to revert an unnecessary "git reset HEAD~1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944826/how-to-revert-an-unnecessary-git-reset-head1)

Comment: Are you sure you typed "~HEAD" and not "HEAD~"? If I type "git show ~HEAD --name-only" I get "fatal: ambiguous argument '~HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree."

Answer (score 15):

I managed to fix this myself.
Found this command and it worked:

```
$ git reset HEAD@{1}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest this but I was afraid it wouldn't work.  Luckily, you didn't do `git reset --hard ~HEAD`.  This would have ended badly for you :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you mistakenly executed `git reset --soft HEAD^1` and want to undo the effect of that command, follow these steps:

1. **Find the Commit SHA**: The first thing you need to do is to get the commit SHA of the commit to which you want to go back.

   Run:

   ```
   git reflog
   ```

   You'll see an output listing of various actions you've performed and their corresponding commit SHA. Look for the entry before the `reset`. It'll typically be at the top of the list, often with a `HEAD@{1}` descriptor next to it. Note down the commit SHA.

   The reflog output might look something like this:

   ```
   7f8e3b9 (HEAD -> main, origin/main) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD^1
   d1a9fab HEAD@{1}: commit: your recent commit message
   ...
   ```

   In this example, `d1a9fab` is the commit SHA you're interested in.
2. **Reset Back to That Commit**: Now that you have the commit SHA, you can reset back to it.

   ```bash
   git reset --soft d1a9fab
   ```

   Replace `d1a9fab` with whatever SHA you obtained from the reflog.

Now, you should be back to where you were before you did the accidental `git reset --soft HEAD^1`.

Remember:

- `--soft` will keep the working directory and staging area the same. If you want to reset everything including the working directory to the way it was, use `--hard` (be very careful with this option as you'll lose any uncommitted changes).

Comment: you should flag duplicate questions to be closed.