# How to undo git reset --soft to get my changes back?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-reset

I had some local changes in my directory that I committed using git commit. Later I realized that by mistake my changes broke my build. So I did a `git reset --soft` on my repo.
But I screwed up, as I did not back up the changes that were all undone, as some of them did contain the new functionality that I wanted. Any help on how to undo a `git reset --soft` operation so that I can get my committed changes back.

Comment: The previous commit should still be in the reflog.  But if you did a soft reset, shouldn't the changes still be in your working copy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510276/undoing-git-reset

Comment: Hi, thanks for the pointer. Actually what I just figured out is that I had forgot to do a "git add" for some of my local files. So when I actually did a commit in the first place, all the changes for those local files which were in "staged" phase, got committed and the unstaged changes got lost..Well now it seems that I am totally screwed. Is there a way out?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

In `$ git reflog` you should find some of your commits. Once you find the latest commit that you want to move to

you should reset back to your commit id `$ git reset _Your_Hash_` , as `$ git reset --soft` just reset the files and not the index or working tree.

Comment: I still have a bunch of changes in `git status`. Before `git reset --soft` these were not there, so this answer as a general undo-this-git-command seems incomplete.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I panicked like hell, when I did git reset --soft HEAD~26 instead of 16 and force pushed.