# Cancel undo commit VSCode

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

Accidentally I press Undo Commit and all my work dissappeared, Is there any way to revert it?
I didn't commit my last changes and that is the work I lost

Comment: VS Code keeps track of your [local history](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_66#_local-history) independent of source control. Can you recover some changes from it?

Comment: Yes it does, but the problem its that I need to restore a complete folder, not file by file  @AnsonH

Answer (score 3):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50092222/6309), VSCode "`Undo Last Commit`" runs `git reset HEAD~`.

That means you can restore your last commit (but not easily your work in progress at the time of the undo) using [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog), and a `git reset --hard <lastSHA1>` (again, make sure you don't have a work in progress, use [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) if needed).

However, for any work in progress, you will need the VSCode local history as mentioned in the comments.