# Undo a git reset file command

Tags: git, git-reset

I just ran this command:

```
 git reset origin/dev -- package-lock.json
```

but I want to do undo it, I want to go back to:

```
 git reset HEAD -- package-lock.json
```

but I think it might be too late to go back to HEAD...how do I undo the original command?

Maybe:

```
 git reset HEAD^ -- package-lock.json
```

?

**Update**: I think I meant to do `git checkout origin/dev -- package-lock.json`, not git reset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undoing git reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510276/undoing-git-reset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git reset commit -- path` means: *copy file `path` from `commit` into index.*

You cannot undo this, as it overwrites whatever file was in the index for that path.

Fortunately, you rarely ever *need* to undo this, because the copy that was in the index is probably also somewhere else too.  If so, just copy *that* copy into the index.  Usually, the copy of any file that is in the index is itself a copy of some other file: either a copy of a committed file, extracted via `git checkout`, or a copy of a work-tree file, added via `git add`.

If the copy that was in the index does not exist anywhere else, you are out of luck.  But this generally only happens with `git add --patch` or `git reset --patch`.

> **Update**: I think I meant to do `git checkout origin/dev -- package-lock.json`

This means: *copy file `package-lock.json` from the commit identified by `origin/dev` into the index, and then copy the index version into the work-tree.*  As with `git reset`, this overwrites whatever was in the index before, and that part cannot be undone.  On successfully overwriting the index version, it also extracts the file into the work-tree, overwriting whatever was in the work-tree.  This, too, cannot be undone—and it's *less* likely that you have a copy of what you had in the work-tree earlier.  So be even more careful with this kind of `git checkout` than you are with the above kind of `git reset`.

In any case, if that *is* what you meant, you can just do it now, overwriting whatever you stuck in the index earlier and also overwriting the work-tree copy.