# How to undo Git reset

Tags: git

I have a branch called: `feature_media`.

I wanted to squash commits by running this command :

```
git reset $(git merge-base master feature_media)
```

This command cancels my last commits and unstages the changes. I want to undo the result of this command and recovering last commits.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that dollar syntax. What does it do?

Comment: @isherwood that's just a shell expansion - it evaluates the command on the inside then passes that as the arg.

Comment: You could check the revision you were on before running reset by running `git reflog`. When you yet the Id of the revision, git reset there. But what you did looks ok. Try with `git reset --soft` and you should get all your changes in the index ready to commit a single commit with all the changes (squashed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to undo 'git reset'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510276/how-to-undo-git-reset)

Comment: @isherwood It's [Command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution). See also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of the commits that your current branch pointed at, from most recent to least recent, by running

```
git reflog [branch-name]
```

where `[branch-name]` is the current branch name. So what you could do is run this command to look at the history of the branch, find the ID of the commit (`[commit-id]`) it pointed at before you ran your `reset` command, and then do

```
git reset [commit-id]
```

You might use the `--hard` option if you want to discard any uncommitted changes in the working directory.

A possible shortcut for this is

```
git reset [branch-name]@{1}
```

which resets the branch to the last commit it pointed at before its current state. That will work if and only if the reset you want to undo is the *last* thing you did to the branch. If you've made any commits or other changes to the branch since then, this won't do the right thing, and that's why I suggested looking at the reflog.

You can also use things like

```
git reset '[branch-name]@{5 hours ago}'
```

if you have a good idea of when the branch last pointed at the thing you want it to point at.

Comment: Is there way to do wit with Gitlens ( VScode) ?

Comment: Possibly, but I don't know. That might be a good thing to ask as a separate followup question.

Comment: I used `git reset HEAD^1` to come to commit id `a` and then in `git reflog` I can see that the commit I want to recover is at `HEAD@{6}`, so I used `git reset HEAD@{6}`. Nothing recovered, `git log` shows that I am still at commit `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Run `git reflog`. Assuming you haven't made further changes, it should produce output like:

```
af32a10 HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to af32a1
7be9d53 HEAD@{1}: commit: foo bar
...
```

Now pick the commit that you wish to restore to. In your case, you likely can run:

```
git reset 'HEAD@{1}'
```