# How to revert a wrong merge on git

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I have 3 main branches in my git repository, `dev`, `release`, and `master`. I make changes into `dev`, then merge it to `release`, and to `master` when its in production. After I made this merges i push the 3 to github.

I've commited a mistake and somehow merge origin's `release` into my local `dev`. You can see in the picture below. I've merged dev into release correctly, but after that there's a merge from origin's `release` into `dev`.

[image]

I'd like to delete this last commit `merge branch 'release' of https://github....` as if it never ocurred.

I've tried to use VSCode revert command:

[image]

But I get this message instead:

```
Error: Unable to Revert Commit
Already up to date!
On branch dev
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/dev'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I revert a Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: Use `git reset --hard <earlier commit>`.

Comment: "Revert" means to create a *new* commit with the inverse changes in Git.

Answer (score 6):

In Git, the `revert` command (used by VS Code behind-the-scenes) does not *delete* the commit(s) in question. Instead, it *creates a new commit* which undoes the changes. See [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) for more about `revert`.

You can use `revert` with a merge commit *if* you specify which "side" of the merge to go back to; e.g.

```
git revert -m 1
```

**However**, this is still not what you are looking for. What you want to do is handled by the [`reset` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).

**BE CAREFUL:** of all the Git commands, `reset` is one of the easier ways to lose your work! It is relatively difficult, [though still possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2531803), to undo the effects of a mistaken `reset`.

To be safe, you can create a backup of your dev branch first:

```
git switch dev
git branch dev-backup
```

The following should remove your merge commit:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

If all goes well, you can delete your backup:

```
git branch -D dev-backup
```