# Intellij Idea cancel "undo commit"

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have undone a local commit, all the files that were in this commit are now gone. Is there a way to revert the branch back to state when this undone commit was present?

Comment: Reset to the previous SHA? Revert? I'm not 100% sure I understand precisely what you're asking--it might be helpful to show the relevant command history and git feedback.

Comment: would it help if I said it did reset --soft ba40bfd2d5a5a961add16....

Comment: what I did is I pressed "Undo commit" in Git window, the git log shows reset --soft command, this is my problem - I want to revert this command

Comment: Once you do "Undo commit" you are prompted to choose a target changelist for these files. They shouldn't be deleted.
 Could you please check your Local Changes to see whether those files are listed there?

Answer (score 0):

Intellij Undo commit uses git reset under the hood - this answer works wonders: [How to undo 'git reset'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510276/how-to-undo-git-reset)