# How to undo git checkout -B branch?

Tags: git

I have some old changes in one branch but this command has reset the branch to my master and cannot be undone by reflog. What should I do?

Log:

```
$ git checkout -B branch
Switched to and reset branch 'branch'
```

Comment: Related, but not exactly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2510276/184546).

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my own question: I managed to find my change back not by reseting the checkout, but by reseting to the old change in the reflog history a while ago. Lucky for me it was still there.

Comment: Note, in the selected answer to the related question, this syntax will help you find what you want a little faster next time: `git reflog show branch`