# How do I undo a "git reset --hard ~HEAD" followed by "git reset ORIG_HEAD"?

Tags: git, git-reset

Originally, I wanted to squash my last 6 commits into one. So I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git) answer and ran the following:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~3
git reset --hard HEAD~2
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Then I saw that my code progress was gone and I was afraid that I might have lost my progress, so I wanted to **undo** that reset. So I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510276/how-to-undo-git-reset) answer and ran:

```
git reset ORIG_HEAD
```

After this, I thought I would get to my most recent code progress, but I found 67 unstaged changes after this last reset and the code doesn't seem to have been recovered.

So, what should I do now to recover my code? I wanted to be very sure before I proceed or try other answers.

Comment: Not sure, but for undo of hard reset, you need to have the commit hash of the original HEAD.

Comment: You need to find the commit hash of where `HEAD` was before `git reset --hard HEAD~3` and then do `git reset --hard <that hash>`. Use `git reflog` to find it.

Comment: Also, be careful, never use hard reset unless you are quite sure.

Comment: Squashing is `reset --soft`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528245/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-mixed-soft-and-hard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `git reflog`, you can see all the commits your HEAD has been on recently. You can then use the commit-ish `HEAD@{N}` to come back to a previousy visited commit.

As you seem to have changed your HEAD 4 times, you should try `git reset --hard HEAD@{4}`.

**Warning:** if you try and don't succeed, it will change your reflog history as you moved your HEAD one more time, so run `git reflog` after each failed attempt and use the git message to identify the right commit.