# I accidentally git reset --hard in the first initial commit, how to restore it back?

Tags: git, git-reset

I noticed error with the initial commit. So I ran 'git reset --hard origin/master' command. After this command it deleted all the files locally and didn't see anything, How can I restore all files

Comment: So you *did* commit your work, and *then* you messed it up? That's good, you'll be able to recover it: [`git reflog` is your friend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71436458/how-do-i-undo-a-git-reset-hard-head-followed-by-git-reset-orig-head).

Answer (score 1):

Use `git reflog` to find the hash correspinding to your "initial commit".

Then `git reset --hard <hash>`. This will restore your files same as the one you had in your initial commit.

Example:

```
$ git reflog
42115cd HEAD@{0}: commit: reset --hard HEAD^: updating HEAD
ab92d4d HEAD@{1}: commit: initial commit
$ git reset --hard ab92d4d
```

After this your files should be restored.

Here is the answer thread in detailed,

[How can I undo git reset --hard HEAD~1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/how-can-i-undo-git-reset-hard-head1)