# Download previous build of project From GitGui

Tags: git, repository

We are using GitGui at my job and I need to download a previous version of our solution.  When I search the Web all I get results for is the GitHub - which is not the same thing.  I looked through the menu bar but cannot find anything that seems relevant.

Comment: Use the "Reset" command: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843260/how-do-you-undo-a-hard-reset-in-git-gui-or-gitk-on-windows

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink I looked up the Reset command and from what it looks like (including the link you provided) that all it is, is for if I commit a new build but did not push it yet then I can roll back the previous build.

That is not what I need.  I need to pull down the previous build from my repository.