# "git am --abort" for long-forgotten patch-attempt throws me back by four weeks

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I tried to play with patches in (Tortoise)git today, apparently for the second time since using git: it complained that I was already in the middle of patching.

So without much thinking, I clicked on "abort" since I didn't care about the old patch-attempt any more, **and now all my commits of the last four weeks are gone**.

What happened? How can git do this to me? ;-)

(as you can see in my own answer below, at least I got my commits back. But changes in the working copy are gone forever, the way I understand it. Quite harsh to any novel user that clicking "Abort" on some far-ago action will at the same time destroy current work without warning... I guess git likes to do its name justice once in a while ;-) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tortoisegit ran a `git am --abort`, which ran a `git --reset hard` back to the state before attempting the first patch (four weeks ago), making all commits since then invisible. There was a discussion about this on [comp.version-control.git](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/118373) back in 2009, where they were thinking about changing the behavior. In any case, it can be undone like any `--reset hard` as described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/undoing-a-git-reset-hard-head1).

Comment: Whoa, 110 votes... I wish I'd been the lucky guy to explain about recovering from reflogs first.