# Redo "Git Reset --hard HEAD^" Command

Tags: git, git-reset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undoing a git reset --hard HEAD~1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/undoing-a-git-reset-hard-head1)

I used the command line:

git reset --hard HEAD^

how can i redo it ?

Comment: yes i mean undo, i used git reset --hard HEAD~1 and worked, thanks

Answer (score 9):

If you want to go back to HEAD ( the previous ) you can do:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

**Note** that working directory changes and staged changes are lost after you do `git reset --hard` and you cannot get them back.

Comment: Also: take a look at `git reflog`.