# How to make "git log" show changesets that are newer than where you have reset to?

Tags: git

If I reset to a changeset that is, let's say `HEAD^`, then `git log --all` no longer displays the newer changeset above the current one. Is there a way to make it display as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`git reflog`](http://fclose.com/p/linux/man/1-git-reflog/) should display the commit previously referenced by HEAD before your reset.
([`git reflog`, your safety net](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html))

See "[Undoing a git reset --hard HEAD~1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/undoing-a-git-reset-hard-head1)" as a concrete example.
You can also try, with `git log` alone, the `-g` option:

```
-g, --walk-reflogs
```

> Instead of walking the commit ancestry chain, walk reflog entries from the most recent one to older ones

After all, `git reflog` can be done by a `git log -g --oneline`.

```
git log --walk-reflogs master # show reflog entries for master
```

---

The [OP rFactor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283055/rfactor) adds:

> Can I filter out everything except Merge and Commit reflogs?
>   For example, I want to get rid of `Checkout` and `Updating HEAD`.

I don't see how you can achieve that without filtering the output.
[Jefromi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119963/jefromi) concurs in the comments:

```
git reflog ... | grep -v 'checkout:\|updating HEAD'
```

> Also after you figure out what commit you want to see, you can then use log normally:

```
git log HEAD@{7} 
# or 
git log <SHA1>
```

Comment: Is there a way I can force `git log` to display it?

Comment: Interesting. One more thing, can I filter out everything except Merge and Commit reflogs? For example, I want to get rid of Checkout and Updating HEAD.

Comment: @rFactor: `git reflog ... | grep -v 'checkout:\|updating HEAD'`

Comment: @rFactor: Also after you figure out what commit you want to see, you can then use log normally: `git log HEAD@{7}` or `git log <SHA1>`