# git reset --hard, how will it affect my commits and branches?

Tags: git

We had a snafu tonight where code checked into git (which gets auto pushed to our application if pushed to the master branch) that caused our site to go down for a bit. I restored an EC2 snapshot to get the site back up, but now I need to cleanup git and get us back on track.

It looks like I need to find the last successful commit to the master branch, grab the first 8 or so characters of it's sha1 id, and run this:

```
git reset --hard jfe2ldj2
git push origin master -f
```

Once I do that, everything on the master branch from commit "jfe2ldj2" an later will be wiped from git and can never be recovered. Am I understanding that correctly?

Also, this will not effect any other branches or commits correct? Meaning, that once I run that command and bring the master branch back to say 6 weeks ago, all of the other branches will remain current. Meaning that if I have a number of release and feature branches and they all have multiple commits since 6 weeks ago, all of those branches and commits will still be there?

Comment: Consider reading ["Reset demystified"](http://git-scm.com/2011/07/11/reset.html) by Scott Chacon.

Comment: @kostix link is broken

Comment: @AidenCullo, that article has since then been reworked to be a part of "The Book" on Git, so [here it is](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified). Anyway, I like the original a bit more—if only for a nice pic of the three trees ;-)—so [here is its archive copy](http://web.archive.org/web/20120511055637/http://git-scm.com/2011/07/11/reset.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Once I do that, everything on the master branch from commit `jfe2ldj2` an later 
>   will be wiped from git and can never be recovered.

As has already been [well covered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/undoing-a-git-reset-hard-head1), if changes were committed they can still be recovered even after `reset --hard`

> Also, this will not effect any other branches or commits correct?

Yes, think of a tree, chopping off one branch leaves the others intact.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the garbage collection... that's good to know. I feel safer about running these sorts of destructive commands knowing that I can recover from them even due to user error.