# I have just nuked 1 week of work with git - any way to fix it?

Tags: git

I've been working on my app for 1 week without commit. I am new to git, so please don't bash me for doing everything on master.

Anyway, I had 1 file that due to a bug got to be 1gb in size. When I deleted it, and made new commit, it would still want to upload big file on push. So I decided to google how to delete commits, and I used this command without reading documentation.

```
    Jans-MacBook-Pro-2:js3 jan$ git reset --hard HEAD~1
HEAD is now at afcb5ad fix dev log
Jans-MacBook-Pro-2:js3 jan$ git reset --hard HEAD~1
HEAD is now at b5ac226 work in progress
Jans-MacBook-Pro-2:js3 jan$ git reset --hard HEAD~1
HEAD is now at e6d938c stylesheet
Jans-MacBook-Pro-2:js3 jan$ git add .
Jans-MacBook-Pro-2:js3 jan$ git commit -a -m 'work in progress'
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

When I realized what happend...well one of worst feelings in the world. Any way I can restore my work? There are so many things I worked on, I don't even know where to start again.

Here is my reflog:

```
Jans-MacBook-Pro-2:js3 jan$ git reflog
e6d938c HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
b5ac226 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
afcb5ad HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
0c7d0d5 HEAD@{3}: commit: fix?
afcb5ad HEAD@{4}: commit: fix dev log
b5ac226 HEAD@{5}: commit: work in progress
e6d938c HEAD@{6}: commit: stylesheet
```

The last push (1 week ago) is stylesheet, all other commits are from today. Ideally, Id like any of them back.

**Progress**
After I've realized what had happend I saved all tabs I had open in vim. Now I get this when I try to restore. How do I fix?

```
    Jans-MacBook-Pro-2:js3 jan$ git checkout afcb5ad
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    app/controllers/find_controller.rb
    app/models/search.rb
    log/development.log
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
Jans-MacBook-Pro-2:js3 jan$
```

Comment: Git gives you lots of ways to save yourself if you make a mistake, but it can't help you restore files that you never committed/stashed/added.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't possible if you didn't push your deleted commits

Comment: http://www.programblings.com/2008/06/07/the-illustrated-guide-to-recovering-lost-commits-with-git/ http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html

Comment: `git reflog` is your friend.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, he deleted the file and committed: “When I deleted it, and made new commit, it would still want to upload big file on push.”

Comment: Time Machine?  (I see you're on a Mac.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use time machine :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git reset` doesn't destroy the commits.

As long as git hasn't cleaned itself up since, you can run `git checkout afcb5ad` to get back the second-to-last commit.

Comment: the problem isn't lost commits, it's lost *uncommitted work* that the `reset --hard` blew away.

Comment: Yes. It's a little bit confusing because of the way that it's written, but it's clear if you take it as a whole. "Been working for 1 week without commit", then did this stuff to remove a commit with a huge file, then tried to commit "work in progress" only to find that there are no changes in the working tree to commit.

Comment: Should I just make a new commit and than run `git checkout afcb5ad`?

Comment: @JanNetherdrake: Yes, or run `git stash`.

Comment: You fine sir, how does one buy you a beer/coffee?

Answer (score 3):

> Ideally, Id like any of them back.

Well you should be able to get back to any of the committed revs.

See the accepted answer here: [How can I undo git reset --hard HEAD~1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/undoing-a-git-reset-hard-head1)

Comment: You fine sir, how does one buy you a beer/coffee?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really reset anything you haven't commited, because nothing has been stored in the object model.