# Undo reverse commit source tree

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I have accidently done a reverse commit of a branch on which I was working on. Is there any way to undo that reverse commit and get my changes back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is the answer you're looking for.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/undoing-a-git-reset-hard-head1/21778#21778)

It shows how to find your committed files in history and reset to them.

Answer (score 1):

If you reseted the head of your branch than you need the old head's sha1. Maybe you can find it in the .git/objects directory by date. (try git show xyz with the suspicious sha's. (suspicious means the modification time can match.))

If you commited a "reverse" commit, than you have to repeat only what you did. (commit an other reverse commit.)
Or you can also reset the head to remove the "reverse" commit from your branch's history. 
(`git reset --soft 'HEAD^'`)

There are a few helpful description: [How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-git-commit)

Answer (score 1):

If you get the SHA of the original commit (the one you later reversed) you can cherry-pick that one back to HEAD.

Or you can just reverse the reverse. It will basically be the same thing.