# Git delete reset hard /master

Tags: git

Following a bad manipulation I have made a "git reset --hard origin/master" on my current working directory. Obviously this erased all my changes which were commited but not pushed. Is it possible to recover them ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I undo git reset --hard HEAD~1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/how-can-i-undo-git-reset-hard-head1)

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately , yes you can still recover your lost commits. The git stores your commmit history and can be viewed using the `reflog` command.

Do this

```
git reflog
```

Find your last commit and do this

```
git reset --hard <commit-id>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are able to recover the state of the file at the last "git add " using this:

`$ git fsck --cache --no-reflogs --lost-found --unreachable  HEAD`

Then take a look at the  files in '.git/lost-found/other'.

Answer (score 0):

If you still know the hash of your last commit before doing the reset, you can check it out, provided the garbage collector has not run yet.

Comment: ah ah :) Is there a way to get the hash ?