# Used git reset --hard, now wants to undo it

Tags: git

I just by mistake used git reset --hard. Now I want to undo this command and bring my changes back. How can I do this?

I used `git reflog` command and see following.

```
6eea708 HEAD@{0}: commit (initial): Initial commit
```

How can I bring my changes back?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/how-can-i-undo-git-reset-hard-head1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move HEAD back to a previous location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in luck because of this bit you put in a comment:

> The thing is that I did not commit those changes. **I first did `git add .`** and then ...

First, let's note that `git add .` stages work-tree contents.  That is, suppose that `.`, your current directory, contains files `foo.txt` and `bar.xml` that are both in the current (HEAD) commit,<sup>1</sup> and you have modified one or both of these.  The `add` step copies the new contents into the underlying repository, and then makes the index/staging-area refer to the new contents.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21227533/1256452) is in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5473/1256452), so this is technically a duplicate, but I think it's worth expanding on a bit, especially since that one answer is buried relatively far down, below the more common case of having used `git reset` to discard a commit.

> ... I used `git reset --hard`

Note that this form of `reset` *does not* discard any commits, but it *does* clear out work-tree files that have been staged.  That is, it not only unstages files—i.e., undoes `git add` and/or `git rm`—just like `git reset --mixed`, it *also* **overwrites the work-tree version of the file** with the committed version.<sup>2</sup>

This makes it difficult to get the staged version back, but not impossible.

The key here is that the file's contents *are* in the repository, stored under their "hash name"—one of those big ugly SHA-1 hashes like `fa49b077972391ad58037050f2a75f74e3671e92`.

If you run:

```
$ git fsck
```

Git will find any hash-names that have nothing referring to them:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
dangling blob fa49b077972391ad58037050f2a75f74e3671e92
```

The index/staging-area used to refer to this file, but `git reset --hard` cleared that out.  So now nothing refers to this `fa49b...` file.

You can extract the file with git plumbing commands, but if there are a bunch of these and you want to refer to them more easily, you can add the `--lost-found` option to `git fsck`, then look in the lost-and-found directory, where these "dangling blob" files have been extracted:

```
$ git fsck --lost-found
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
dangling blob fa49b077972391ad58037050f2a75f74e3671e92
$ cd .git/lost-found/other
$ ls
fa49b077972391ad58037050f2a75f74e3671e92
$ cat fa49b077972391ad58037050f2a75f74e3671e92 
new file
$
```

(I only added, then reset away, the one file; if there were many files you would have to sift through them all to find any good ones.)

When you are done rooting through the lost-found bin contents, it is probably a good idea to remove them (`cd .git/lost-found && rm -rf *`), although they are largely harmless to leave there—they just occupy space.  You can run `git fsck --lost-found` again later to repopulate it (with any then-dangling commits and blobs).

Note that this method will fail if you wait too long—these dangling blob objects are not semi-protected (by reflog entries) the way discarded commits are.  By default, though, leftover objects are not pruned for 14 days anyway.  This means you have two weeks, instead of about a month as for commits.

There is one more trap here, not that it will affect people in practice.  The file I reset away had one line reading `new file` (plus a newline).  Suppose that, for whatever reason, some *other* file, in some existing (not discarded) commit, has the exact same contents.  When I `git add`ed the file, Git would have computed this same "true name" hash—the true name of *any* file containing nothing but the one line `new file` is always `fa49b077972391ad58037050f2a75f74e3671e92`, in any repository anywhere on the planet<sup>3</sup>—and would have just referred to the *existing copy* of that file.  Resetting it away and running `git fsck`, Git will not notice a dangling blob, because at this point it is *not dangling*: some *other* commit refers to file `fa49b077972391ad58037050f2a75f74e3671e92`, perhaps under the same path name, or perhaps under some other path.

---

<sup>1</sup>It also adds files that are not in the `HEAD` commit, but I did not want to get into all the side issues of worrying about `.gitignore` directives.  See footnote 2. :-)

<sup>2</sup>If the file is newly added, `git reset --hard` still removes the file from the work-tree.  This is where the `.gitignore` complication comes in: if the file was ignored, it wasn't added, but then `git reset --hard` did not remove it either.  If it *was* added, it's in the repository and we are back to the "file existed in `HEAD`" case.  So this all comes out in the wash anyway.

<sup>3</sup>This suggests a method of attack on Git repositories, consisting of using Google as a massive indexing engine: search blob hashes until you find some hash *H* that repeats, but refers to two different contents *C*<sub>1</sub> and *C*<sub>2</sub>.  Then, knowing that someone will want to use repository *R*, which has neither version of that blob, to hold content *C*<sub>1</sub> in the future, make a commit in *R* holding content *C*<sub>2</sub> instead.  No *new* commit can now contain content *C*<sub>1</sub> since Git will hash it to *H* and decide that it is already in the repository.

Practical, this attack is not. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can just cherry-pick the one commit you want

```
git cherry-pick <commit_id>
```

Comment: The thing is that I did not commit those changes. I first did 'git add .' and then I used `git reset --hard`

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to recover the changes unless they were once part of a commit. I thought you said you got the commit id from `reflog` but weren't sure how to recover it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your `git reflog` output, you can just do

```
git reset HEAD@{0}
```

or

```
git reset 6eea708
```