# How to recover untracked files after doing git hard reset (git add and git commit were not done)!

Tags: git, github

I had some untracked files in my branch *A*. I forgot to add and commit those changes and did `git push -u origin/A`. After that I checked out branch *B* and did `git reset --hard origin/B`. After doing these steps all the changes were lost in branch *A*. Is there any way to recover those changes/untracked files?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147680/accidentally-reverted-to-master-lost-uncommitted-changes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After reset --hard all my untracked files are gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52042030/after-reset-hard-all-my-untracked-files-are-gone)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+recover+untracked+files+hard+reset

Comment: Git is not going to help you here, it does not know about files until you add them. Your IDE may save you, many of them have local history. `git reset --hard` is one of the few dangerous git commands, don't included it in your workflow. In this case you could have used `git checkout -B <current_branch> origin/B`