# How to rollback committed data in git

Tags: git

I committed by data using git commit -m, followed by git pull and found there is an overwrite by different team, In order to solve it I ran a git reset --hard and few other commands, but I messed up everything and lost my commit. Is there a way I can rollback to my last commit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I undo git reset --hard HEAD~1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/how-can-i-undo-git-reset-hard-head1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your question what you did exactly. But if nothing else works, I'd try `git reflog`. Since you commited your changes before `git pull`, reflog should be able to give you the commit hash of your head before you performed the git pull.

Comment: Thank you Sir, You saved my Day

Comment: Been there :) Please mark the answer as correct if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try resetting to a particular commit point immediately before you pulled your team's code if you know the commit hash

The attached link should be useful to you 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12049323/1592471