# I accidentally deleted everything when doing git commit

Tags: git

I have no idea what happened. I tried to commit, and when I went to push to master it said I was up to date and nothing happened.

```
(py35) $ git status
On branch jt
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   rt/models.py
modified:   rt/test_models.py

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

../.DS_Store
.DS_Store
rt/.DS_Store
rt/migrations/.DS_Store
rt/migrations/0005_auto_20170323_2255.py
rt/migrations/0006_department_org.py
rt/migrations/0007_auto_20170323_2309.py
rt/migrations/0008_auto_20170323_2311.py
rt/migrations/0009_auto_20170323_2313.py
rt/migrations/0010_auto_20170323_2315.py

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
(py35) $ git add .
(py35) $ git commit -m "edits to models, fixed up team and dept, tested with presentation and working paper"
[jt cea85b9] edits to models, fixed up team and dept, tested with presentation and working paper
 Committer: Jonathan <xxxxxxxxxx>
 Your name and email address were configured automatically based
 on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
 You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly. Run the
 following command and follow the instructions in your editor to edit
 your configuration file:

 git config --global --edit

 After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

 git commit --amend --reset-author

 11 files changed, 398 insertions(+), 79 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 mysite/.DS_Store
 create mode 100644 mysite/rt/.DS_Store
 create mode 100644 mysite/rt/migrations/.DS_Store
 create mode 100644 mysite/rt/migrations/0005_auto_20170323_2255.py
 create mode 100644 mysite/rt/migrations/0006_department_org.py
 create mode 100644 mysite/rt/migrations/0007_auto_20170323_2309.py
 create mode 100644 mysite/rt/migrations/0008_auto_20170323_2311.py
 create mode 100644 mysite/rt/migrations/0009_auto_20170323_2313.py
 create mode 100644 mysite/rt/migrations/0010_auto_20170323_2315.py
 (py35) $ git push origin master
 Everything up-to-date
```

After this I did something dumb and ran

```
git log -1
git reset --hard dd882d0aa067c60dd92610d1fa6b32548e70f596
```

Which then changed the files back to what they were at my last commit. Even changing what I had open in my IDE.

How can I get all the changes I worked on today back? I know that they are there because when I look in /.git/lost-found/other, they are there. I'm not sure how to use them though.

Comment: Does `get reflog --all` give you anything? You can checkout to earlier HEAD. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21778/1233686).

Comment: So you use bitbucket or github? Go and get the commit you want and do git reset --hard [commit #]

Comment: `git reset --hard cea85b9` will put you back.

Comment: I think the reason you couldn’t push is that you don’t have an upstream branch specified, I think. If you did, the `git status` would have `Your branch is ahead of origin/master by N commits` or some similar message (where `origin/master` might be `origin/jt` or some other remote branch). Since you haven’t specified an upstream branch for `jt`, it thinks it doesn’t need to push anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Following command may recover by pointing HEAD to previous commit:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

Please make a backup copy of the entire project directory **before typing this** just to prevent any confusion for the solution.

Comment: And in general, you can use `git reflog` to see where `HEAD` has been before, even if you have moved around a bit since then.