# Recover files not yet added to GIT

Tags: git, laravel, file, recover

I had a ton of files, pictures and documents in a git directory that was used for profile pictures and etc... I did an update to my production server and broke the site so I went and did a git reset --hard to the last working revision which lost all of the pictures and documents.

Is there a way to undo git's actions? I am hoping there is a way to get back to the way it was. Thank you for your time.

Comment: check this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/how-can-i-undo-git-reset-hard-head1

Comment: Thank you so much for the link, but I saw that they said if you did --hard it wont be able to be recovered. So I might be literally screwed here :/

Comment: If you *did* add these files, even without later doing `git commit`, the files are at least temporarily squirreled away in the repository. If not, you are indeed s-word-ed.

Comment: I did NOT add them, :( lol geez. The messes I cause :/ . Definitely a learning experience.

Comment: git reset shouldn't do anything to untracked files afaik...  you must have done something else beyond a reset

Comment: Oh yeah? So If I have untracked files they shouldnt be deleted or removed when doing a git reset --hard?

Comment: Your correct the files were NOT deleted, I thought that git reset --hard would  delete everything in the git repository including files that have not been added to git in order to restore it to the complete state of the git commit i was restoring from. No files are deleted and the project is perfectly safe. thank you so much for your knowledge and insight on this :) Please make this an answer and I will accept it. I will use this as a learning experience and make sure to do lots of research before panic on here. :)

Answer (score 0):

to undo `git reset --hard` try do a `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}` but if you did more things since you screwed up it might not work. do a `git reflog` to find the latest position of HEAD and do `git reset --hard HEAD@{that_number_you_find}`

Comment: I tried this and it didnt seem to bring back my files. Do I need to do something else after this to recover the deleted files?

Comment: can you do a `git reflog` to find your latest working commit?

Answer (score 0):

you can see you moves with `git log` and the identificator of the commit if you see you commit you can get the files