# Getting data back after git reset --hard

Tags: git

I accidentally did :

```
git fetch && git reset --hard origin/mybranch
```

on production and looks like I am busted. There were some changes made but added using `git add` and `git commit`. How could I get my data back?

I tried:

```
git reflog
git reset HEAD@{1}
```

but I cannot see the changes made. How could I get them back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I undo git reset --hard HEAD~1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/how-can-i-undo-git-reset-hard-head1)

Comment: Try using `git show` with various `git reflog` entries, maybe it's stored a bit farther down.

Comment: @MrTux I tried that, but it did not help me. Could you help me with this?

Comment: We’re those changes stashed or committed?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, they were committed

Comment: May you add the output of `git reflog` to the question and show us which commit you'd like to get back to?

Comment: What do you mean by "on production". Did you push force to the remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `git add` a file, it will add that file to the object database and place the object information in the staging area.  When you run a `git reset`, the file is removed from the index, but it is *not* removed from the object database.  As a result, you can examine the object database for objects that are "dangling".

For example:

If I create a new file and `git add` it:

```
% echo "new file" > newfile.txt
% git add newfile.txt
% git ls-files --stage
100644 40ee2647744341be918c15f1d0c5e85de4ddc5ed 0       file.txt
100644 3748764a2c3a132adff709b1a6cd75499c11b966 0       newfile.txt
```

And then I reset, notice that `newfile.txt` disappears from the index:

```
% git reset --hard origin/mybranch
% git ls-files --stage
100644 40ee2647744341be918c15f1d0c5e85de4ddc5ed 0       file.txt
```

However, the file remains in the object database, and can be recovered.  The easiest way to do this is to [download and install the `git-recover` program](https://github.com/ethomson/git-recover) in interactive mode:

```
% git recover -i
Recoverable orphaned git blobs:

3748764a2c3a132adff709b1a6cd75499c11b966  (Thu 15 Jun 2017 12:20:22 CEST)
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
> veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
> commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate

Recover this file? [y,n,v,f,q,?]:
```

`git-recover` looks for files in the object database that are *not* committed (or in the index).  You can find out more about `git-recover` in [the blog post announcing it](https://edwardthomson.com/blog/introducing_git_recover.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check your `git status`.

If you ran `git reset HEAD@{1}` (instead of `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`) the files on disk will not be changed, and will still hold the content of `origin/mybranch`.
These files will appear as modified in `git status`.

If such is the case, just discard these changes :

```
git checkout .
```