# gitlab commit revert 3 instead of 2 times

Tags: gitlab, commit, git-revert

i accidentally reverted commit 3 times instead of 2 using these command 
git reset HEAD~3

i wanted to do git reset HEAD~2
any way to undo git reset HEAD~3 ?

Comment: Did you push the code to the remote? 
If No, then your changes are in local and you can check out to your current branch.

Comment: no i haven't pushed yet so what i do now exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I undo git reset --hard HEAD~1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/how-can-i-undo-git-reset-hard-head1)

Comment: `git reset HEAD@{1}`

this would help

Comment: git reset HEAD@{1} what it will do?

Comment: It will move the head to the recently pushed commit

Comment: hey it worked after doing git reset HEAD@{1} , I did git reset HEAD~2 and everything is back to normal. thank you.