# I lost some commits when I use git reset

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have some commits on the same branch like this
X1 -> X2 -> X3 -> Y1 -> X4 -> X5

And then after I commit X5, I did reset HEAD to Y1 with

> git reset --hard Y1

After that, commits X4 and X5 be lost. It's normal, but I still lost commit X2 and X3. So I did not understand why that is. Could you please help me to explain that? 
Thank you

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/q/5473/1256452 answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

If X3 is the parent commit of Y1, you should not have lost it:

A `git log` should still be able to list X3 ans X2 as ancestors of Y1.

If not, as commented, you can cancel your `reset --hard` with `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`