# Recover data after command git reset --hard

Tags: git, git-reset

I wrote some code after the last commit. 
After that, I accidentally did git reset --hard.
My code rolled back to the last commit.

Can I restore uncommitted changes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I undo git reset --hard HEAD~1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/how-can-i-undo-git-reset-hard-head1)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-reset%5D+undo+hard+reset

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, no. The data is not preserved in the file system; an end user cannot recover it.

However, `git` doesn't go out of its way to eradicate it, so a [data recovery expert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_recovery#Overwritten_data) might be able to find some (or all) of it.