# how to go back to previous head on commit on local machine

Tags: git, github

I was working on a project which was committed on GitHub. I **made some changes** and tried to commit it to the repo, But I got the error saying `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 3 commits.`

So I tried to go back to the branch `origin/main` and I did `git reset --hard origin/master`

Now I was on the main branch. So I pushed the code on Github. Code got pushed but it was not reflected in the repo.

And When I came back to the editor **all the changes I made on Local machine were gone** it is not there.

I need my changes made codes back on my local machine.

Please Help!

Comment: How did you push the reset?

Comment: normally using `git push`

Comment: Hang on. Why did you reset in the first place? It's expected that when work is done locally the local branch becomes "ahead" of the origin branch.

Comment: It was not getting pushed. That's why I went back to main branch

Comment: Why though? Didn't you want to keep the changes?

Comment: _"It was not getting pushed"_ --- Why? What was the error?

Comment: `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 3 commits.` this is not an error , but rather informing you that your local branch is modified and the next step here was to do a `git push` to push your changes to remote.

Comment: I am a new bee. Since I was getting the error and the code was not getting pushed so I searched StackOverflow and it said I have to go back to the main branch in order to push so I came back to the main branch. and pushed but after the code gets pushed all the changed made were gone.

Comment: but I did `git push` and it was not pushing my code so I thought I have to go back to main branch

Comment: try to run `git reflog` and see if you see the last commit which you want in the list . you can then run `git reset --soft <commit-hash> of the commit where you want your HEAD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I undo git reset --hard HEAD~1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/how-can-i-undo-git-reset-hard-head1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I got the error saying `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 3 commits`.

This is not an error.  It's just information: your Git is telling you that, as far as it knows, you have three commits that they don't.

> So I tried to go back to the branch `origin/main` and I did `git reset --hard origin/master`

That tells your Git: *Please discard my three commits, and any unsaved work too.*  It will have done so.

The good news is that *commits* are considered highly valuable—almost semi-sacred—in Git, and discarded ones can usually be retrieved for a minimum of at least 30 days.  Unsaved work is not recoverable this way though.

The answers in the linked question ([How can I undo git reset --hard HEAD~1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5473/1256452)) will let you get those three commits back.  For unsaved (un-committed) work that you want back, you will need some other non-Git method to recover that.  If there is no such work you are in good shape.